# how to use Global Variable in android module

Tags: android

I used a singleton in the library to save the data, but sometime found that the user returned a null when the user got the variable of singleton .Is there any other way?

I am currently using the singleton mode.

```
public class Factory {

    private static Factory sInstance = null;

    private final Config mConfig;
    public Factory(Config config) {
        mConfig = config;
    }

    public static Factory getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Some users on the line find that the following call will return null.

```
Factory.getInstance().mConfig
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the base android.app.Application class and add member variables like so:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private String someVariable;

    public String getSomeVariable() {
        return someVariable;
    }

    public void setSomeVariable(String someVariable) {
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
    }
}
```

In your android manifest you must declare the class implementing android.app.Application (add the `android:name=".MyApplication"` attribute to the existing application tag):

```
<application 
  android:name=".MyApplication" 
  android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then in your activities you can get and set the variable like so:

```
// set
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable("foo");

// get
String s = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I can't write the method in the application because I created a public library that will be packaged with aar files for use by other project groups in the company.